# How to register MessageBodyWriter and MessageBodyReader in Jersey 2.x

Tags: java, xml, jersey

I am implementing RESTful services using `jersey` api and I've come know that I need to register the custom xmlWriter and xmlReader. Client code implements MessageBodyWriter and I need to know ho0w to register it in server side because I am getting `MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException` for media type application/xml.

MessageBodyWriter code

```
public class SendDocumentsServiceRequestXMLWriter extends BaseMessageBodyWriter implements MessageBodyWriter<SendDocumentsRequest> {

public boolean isWriteable( Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType ) {
    return type == SendDocumentsRequest.class && !mediaType.isWildcardType() 
            && !mediaType.isWildcardSubtype() && mediaType.isCompatible( MediaType.valueOf( "application/xml" ) );
}

public long getSize( SendDocumentsRequest t, Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType ) {
    return 0;
}

public void writeTo( SendDocumentsRequest t, Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType,
    MultivaluedMap<String, Object> httpHeaders, OutputStream entityStream ) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
    try {
        ESignatureClientJAXBContextFactory.getMarshaller( SendDocumentsRequest.class ).marshal( t, entityStream );
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new ESignatureClientException( e );
    }
}
```

}

How can I register this class so that Jersey picks it up?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

put `@Provider` on your implementation class along with `@Produces` or `@Consumes` depending on Writer or Reader.

Here's a example:http://memorynotfound.com/jax-rs-messagebodywriter/

Comment: I still get the exception. MessageBodyWriter not found.

Comment: @Mike how have you configured your project, i mean what container and dependencies and are you using web.xml to setup your rest application or subclassing `Application` and using `@ApplicationPath`.

Comment: I got everything setup. In web.xml I got the jersey container servlet and the packages. The only thing is that it cannot find the MessageBodyWriter.

Comment: @Mike just subclass `Application` and use `getClasses()` to register the Writer and provide init-params like `<init-param>
    <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
    <param-value>org.foo.MyApplicationWhichExtendsApplication</param-value>
</init-param>` in your `ServletContainer` .